# is_convertible for multiple arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, sfinae, type-traits

Suppose I don't have `std::is_convertible` for whatever reason and want to implement it myself. The standard says something along these lines:

> The predicate condition for a template specialization `is_convertible<From, To>` shall be satisfied if and only if the return expression in the following code would be well-formed, including any implicit conversions to the return type of the function:
>
> ```
> To f() {
>     return declval<From>();
> }
> ```

Okay, no big deal, I can do it like this (Note argument order opposite to the one in `std::is_convertible`, this is intentional and irrelevant to the issue):

```
template <typename To_, typename From_>
class my_is_convertible {
    private:
        template <typename To>
        struct indirector {
            indirector(To);
        };

        template <typename To, typename From>
        struct tag {};

        template <typename To, typename From>
        static auto test(tag<To, From>)
            -> decltype(indirector<To>(std::declval<From>()), std::true_type());
        static auto test(...)
            -> std::false_type;

    public:
        static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(tag<To_, From_>()))::value;
};
```

This seems to work as intended, and as far as I can tell does the same thing.

Now I can distinguish between implicit and explicit (or none at all) constructors:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

struct Test {
    Test(A);
    explicit Test(B);
}; 

int main() {   
    std::cout << my_is_convertible<Test, A>::value; // true 
    std::cout << my_is_convertible<Test, B>::value; // false
    return 0;
}
```

So far, so good. Now, I want to do the same with multiple argument constructors. This didn't make sense prior to `c++11` as there was no way to call multiargument constructor implicitly. But now we have brace enclosed initializer list syntax, and `explicit` keyword on multiargument constructor makes a difference.

Let us extend the definition:

> The predicate condition for a template specialization `my_is_convertible_many<To, From...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the return expression in the following code would be well-formed, including any implicit conversions to the return type of the function:
>
> ```
> To f() {
>     return {declval<From>()...};
> }
> ```

To implement it I went the obvious way:

```
template <typename To_, typename... From_>
class my_is_convertible_many {
    private:
        template <typename To>
        struct indirector {
            indirector(To);
        };

        template <typename To, typename... From>
        struct tag {};

        template <typename To, typename... From>
        static auto test(tag<To, From...>)
            -> decltype(indirector<To>({std::declval<From>()...}), std::true_type());
        static auto test(...)
            -> std::false_type;

    public:
        static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(tag<To_, From_...>()))::value;
};
```

This correctly reports `true` in the presence of matching implicit constructor and `false` if the is no matcing constructor. But it fails to compile if there is an explicit matching constructor (at least on gcc 4.8.1):

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

struct Test {
    Test(A, A);
    //Test(B, B);
    explicit Test(C, C);
}; 

int main() {    
    std::cout << my_is_convertible_many<Test, A, A>::value; // true, correct
    std::cout << my_is_convertible_many<Test, B, B>::value; // false, correct
    std::cout << my_is_convertible_many<Test, C, C>::value; // error
    return 0;
}
```

The error is about attempting to implicitly call explicit constructor, which on gcc sounds like this:

```
main.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class To, class ... From> static decltype (((my_is_convertible_many<To_, From_>::indirector<To>)({(declval<From>)()...}), std::true_type())) my_is_convertible_many<To_, From_>::test(my_is_convertible_many<To_, From_>::tag<To, From ...>) [with To = To; From = {From ...}; To_ = Test; From_ = {C, C}] [with To = Test; From = {C, C}]':
main.cpp:21:73:   required from 'constexpr const bool my_is_convertible_many<Test, C, C>::value'
main.cpp:37:54:   required from here
main.cpp:17:97: error: converting to 'Test' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'Test::Test(C, C)'
         static auto test(tag<To, From...>) -> decltype(indirector<To>({std::declval<From>()...}), std::true_type());
                                                                                                 ^
```

Which is sensible. I, however, expect this overload of `test` to sfinae out and the other one to be used instead, thus producing no error.

So the question is: Why doesn't this happen, and what can I do about it?

Comment: To me this does not look like `is_convertible` but `is_constructible_with`

Comment: @Vinzenz I just use standard naming. `std::is_constructible` checks whether object of specified type can be constructed explicitly from arguments of specified types. `std::is_convertible` checks if object of one type can be converted to object of another type implicitly (either by constructor call of conversion operator). I am trying to extend the latter, thus the name. This is irrelevant either way.

Comment: gcc source code says: "When converting from an init list we consider explicit constructors, but actually trying to call one is an error." which sounds like it may be on purpose? Or did it just forget about sfinae? In any case the patch to change it is trivial (1 or 2 lines in cp/call.c). Please file a PR with gcc if you don't get a convincing answer that the code is illegal. By the way, did you check with other compilers?

Comment: *"This seems to work as intended, and as far as I can tell does the same thing."* Not entirely. Consider arrays and function types: They decay as function parameters, but are illegal to be returned.

Comment: @MarcGlisse In most contexts, they are right? Just not in SFINAE?  Maybe?

Comment: Compiles and runs as you expect with clang 3.3

Comment: Fixed in gcc-4.9 (http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=206302). Please don't forget to file a bug at http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ next time.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Maybe you should put that as an answer so this question can be taken off the unanswered question list?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I agree with SamB, you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc was recently [patched](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=206302) and version 4.9 will accept the code. clang accepts it as well, so the code is probably fine. That doesn't tell you how to work around the issue with older versions of gcc, sorry.